# Performance monitoring for ASP.NET MVC2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, iis, monitoring

I would like to know if there is an equivalent of "New Relic RPM" or "JavaMelody" for ASP.NET MVC2 ? I can't find anything about monitoring on ASP.NET MVC2...

Any idea ? How do you monitor the performances of you ASP.NET MVC2 applications ?

http://www.newrelic.com/

http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New Relic now supports ASP.NET monitoring (still in beta) :

http://www.newrelic.com/

Answer (score 1):

For real world uptime/performance monitoring, we use outside services such as BrowserMob. For internals, an ASP.NET MVC app is just a ASP.NET app as far as IIS is concerned, so your normal ASP.NET/IIS monitoring tools do just fine.

By normal tools I'd start with the performance counters for IIS and ASP.NET. [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972959.aspx) is perhaps a good place to start.

I should add the underlying point here is, unlike ruby and some java stuff, you are building on a very solid, instrumented platform here. There is lots of data there, and tools to make it more understandable.

Comment: And how do you monitor IIS and ASP.NET ? I've never done that before.